# Phaser pointer events not working in WebView (Xamarin Forms) C#

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, webview, phaser-framework

I have create a simple animation screen using phaser and its **rendering perfect** and **invoking all pointer events** like pointerover, pointerout, pointerup and pointerdown on button `btn` as expected for **browser**. But when I render same game using **WebView** its rendering screen but **its not invoking** any **pointer events**. To confirm JavaScript is working I have tested by adding `eventlistner` on `window` and it was working.

```
    var config = {
        type: Phaser.CANVAS,
        width: 650,
        height: 900,
        canvas: document.getElementById('myCustomCanvas'),
        scale: {
            mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
            width: 750,
            height: 1334,
            parent: 'game'
          },
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity: { y: 0 }
            }
        },
    scene : {
        preload: function(){game.preload(this, 'asset_url');},
        create: function(){game.create(this);},
        update: function(){game.update(this);},
        }
    };
    


function game(config) {

     this.start = function(config)
     {
       this.phaserGame = new Phaser.Game(config);
     };

    this.create = function()
    {
      var btn = this.scene.add.sprite(375, 665, 'btn');
      btn.setInteractive()
        .on('pointerover', () => {
            console.log('pointerover');
        })
        .on('pointerout', () => {
            console.log('pointerout');
        })
        .on('pointerdown', () => {
            console.log('pointerdown');
        })
        .on('pointerup', () => {
            console.log('pointerup');
        });
    };
}
```

I am using Xamarin Forms WebView to render game in mobile. My setting for WebView is as follow.

```
var webView = CreateNativeControl();
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new HTMLGameWebClient(this));
            webView.Settings.LightTouchEnabled = true;
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            webView.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false;

            SetNativeControl(webView);
```

I also have conditional CSS which is used only if canvas is rendering in mobile.

```
canvas {
    width: 100vw !important;
    height: unset;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any helps or suggestions.

Comment: Hi, do you test it in android device?

Comment: Yes I am testing in android Samsung s6

Comment: Have you tried setting `webview.requestFocus()` like the comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519559/handle-touch-events-inside-webview-in-android) suggests?